# how make maple return polar form in degrees

Tags: maple

Is there a way to have Maple use and return complex numbers in polar format, using degrees?

Something like below...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting to automatically *return* in that way.

But you can set up utility procedures do various parts. For example

1. convert something into **degpolar** form (like [convert](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=convert%2Fpolar) to **polar**, but with degrees rather than radian as the context)
2. pretty-printing (2D Math markup) of something in that `degpolar` form, in the manner you've shown
3. turning something in that form back into the usual complex form

First, some utility procedures, to illustrate,

```
restart;
`convert/degpolar`:=proc(x)
   degpolar(abs(x),180/Pi*argument(x));
end proc:
`print/degpolar`:=proc(ma,ar)
   uses Typesetting;
   mrow(Typeset(`&angle;`(ma,ar)),mi("&deg;"));
end proc:
`evalc/degpolar`:=proc(ma,ar)
   ma*(cos(ar*Pi/180)+I*sin(ar*Pi/180));
end proc:
```

And now an example of use (for which I won't show the output since it gets marked up by the Maple GUI),

```
a := 1/2+sqrt(3)/2*I;

ans := convert(a, degpolar);

evalc(ans);
```

And now an example where you enter something in that form,

```
ex2 := degpolar(4, 225);

evalc(ex2);
```

I think that you'll find that the argument of `1/2+1/2*i*3^(1/2)` is `Pi/3`, not `2*Pi/3`.

If you want you could instead assign that `convert/degpolar` to `&angle;`, and then be able to use the "angle" symbol from the left-panel palettes, for marked-up 2D Input. That might be more advanced than you're expecting. See also [here](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/227870-How-To-Do-simple-Vector-Calculation-with-Example#answer262141) and [here](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/223846-Convert-Complex-Number-In-To-Phasor-Angle#comment245773) (for code that attempts "phasors" in a few ways).